# flow of method call in payment method

Tags: magento-1.8, payment-methods

I would like to know the flow of calls to various methods in `payment method` of magento. Like when do `authorize()`, `capture()`, `refund()` etc. gets called? And what could be the possible scenario which may influence it (if any)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost all payment methods provide functionality to block and then to get the money from customer. Also you can return money back.

Usually workflow is like this:

- Creating order - `authorize()` - money are blocked on customers account but still are there.
- Creating invoice - `capture()` - block money are transferred from customers to your account
- Creating credit memo - `refund()` - amount is returned to customers account.

Some payment methods you can configure to process `authorize()` and `capture()` during creating order at the same time.

Comment: thanks for your time to reply but I'm working on a payment gateway where `capture()` is being called before `authorize()`. So I'm looking for where from these `capture()` or `authorize()` first get called

Comment: Please do not change the way how magento calls `authorize()` and `capture()` methods. Try to think more abstract. Magento's `authorize` is blocking money and `capture` is getting them. If your payment's gateway has different names for this actions as magento, you still can process gateways `capture` in magento's `authorize` and gateways `authorize` in mageto's `capture`.

Comment: Well I'd not changed the way of magento method call but in my case `capture()` is being called first. How could I find what's wrong there?

Comment: What happened when you create order in frontend?

Comment: there's a `cc` form as it extends `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Cc` and after click on `Place Order` my order gets submitted. In my payment gateway account there is an entry for that too. I tried logging as `Mage::log()` in `capture()` and `authorize()`. so, in my log file there an entry from `capture()` then after `authorize()`. Currently I'm working in `sandbox` mode